# Linking outcome probabilities between two related training examples

Tags: logistic, caret, resampling, constraint, bradley-terry-model

```
# Setting up model in Caret, simple cross validation and preprocessing

Tcontrolparam = trainControl("cv",savePredictions = TRUE, summaryFunction = 
twoClassSummary, classProbs = T, returnResamp = "final")

Preprocessing.Options = c("center","scale","nzv","YeoJohnson")

# Run model

 set.seed(0)
Model.GLM = train(x = Predictor.Vars, y = Result,
                         method = "glm",
                         metric = "ROC",
                         preProcess = Preprocessing.Options,
                         trControl = Tcontrolparam)


# Predict on new data - generates probability for each team

Predictions = predict(Model.GLM, New.Data, type = "prob")

# Post process probabilities so that each game, and the teams for each game add to 1.

Predictions.Post.Processing =  Predictions%>%
  group_by(Game)%>%
  mutate(Finalised.Win.Prob = Win.Prob/sum(Win.Prob))
```

I have an interesting question that I am yet to find an answer for in the general literature, so here goes nothing. Basically out of ideas.

I am trying to run a GLM (logistic reg) model in caret on a training data set that has ~2000 rows of data. In the data set each row has a related pair so they are not totally independant. I am modelling sports data for 2 different teams from the same game (hence the pair and 2 rows per game).

I am currently estimating the win probabilities for each team, for each game, however these do not numerically add up to 1. As they should do given it is for the same game. I am currently post processing so that they do add up to 1. This now leads to my question;

Is it possible to train the model in caret by building in the post processing (e.g linking of the two teams) and making the probs = 1, inside the resampling process/modelling building process?

Any thoughts or ideas - no matter how abstract they are would be appreciated!

EDIT: The below image is an example of the data set. In this example, weight, height, exp.game & exp.years are the variables being trained on. The model is trained to predict win/loss for each team and these probabilities are outputed in the lose and win columns respectively.

The yellow and white bands depict each game respectively. As in these are the two teams that are versing each other.

The finalised.win.prob is the post processing version to ensure that the probabilities for each team add to 1. As I say above, i want to be able to build this into the modeling training/resampling as opposed to just doing it post.

Comment: Could you give some more details on the data?

Comment: Done! @kjetil b halvorsen

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: Could you also give details on the logistic regression model you where fitting? (with code) And, which sport is this? Probably obvious for an american ... The data contains a *margin*, is that a number of scores? was that used in the modeling, how?

Comment: Maybe you should look into bradley-terry models, for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33380/how-to-set-up-data-for-bradley-terry-model-in-r and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley%E2%80%93Terry_model

Comment: Thanks @kjetilbhalvorsen I will have a look at those links. I will put some simple code together and post it in the next couple of days. In the data set, the margin is the difference between team scores. The sport is Australian Rules Football (I am an Aussie). I am training the model on the win/loss however  not the margin (that is just a variable that is interesting to look at week to week). Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have added some code up the top. Let me know if that helps.